# How to include all files inside a folder using clojure

Tags: clojure

How to include all files inside a folder using clojure.

Here is my code:

```
(defn LoadFiles[]
    (include "utils")
)
(LoadFiles)
```

But the above code is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "include"?  do you want to `require` them?  or load the content?

Comment: I want to load all the contents from the files..

Comment: then i'd go for something like this `(filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq (io/file "utils")))`

Comment: `(defn LoadFiles[]
   (filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq (io/file "cljfiles")))
)
(LoadFiles)` 
This is full my code.
Is it right? But it's not working.

Comment: please add all your answers to the question to improve it.  "does not work" is not helpfull at all.  also add what data structure you expect that `LoadFiles` to return - above scribble of code will only give the the files of that directory - if you need something else, you will have to shape that file sequence into what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there's no `include` in clojure (correct me if i'm wrong).
You should use `use` or `require` for that.

This one should probably work (for all the .clj files in `utils` top level, but you can easily extend it to be recursive):

```
(defn list-sources [path]
  (map #(str path "." (second (re-matches #"^(\w+)\.clj$" (.getName %))))
       (filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq path))))

(run! #(require (vector (symbol %) :refer :all))
      (list-sources (java.io.File. "utils")))
```

Comment: I tried with above code and received the below error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: run! in this context, compiling:(/home/user/Projects/Clojure/clojure-1.5.1/file.clj:5:1)

Comment: oh, `run!` was added in clojure 1.7.. for your version you can use `(dorun (map #(require ...`

Comment: Can I use like this : `(load-file "utils/file-one.clj")`? I need to customize a configuration file for that I need to include all the clj files from a folder. I'm a newbie to this technology..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
(defn load-files [dir]
  (doseq [f (file-seq (File. dir))
          :when (.isFile f)]
    (load-file (.getAbsolutePath f))))

(load-files "utils")
```

Comment: I tried with above code and received the below error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: File, compiling:(/home/user/Projects/Clojure/clojure-1.5.1/file.clj:2:23)